# How to `load dynamically page` in same template using `meteor js`

Tags: meteor

I need how to `load dynamically` page loading in same page using **meteor js**.I will develop for `Admin panel` ,after login Admin display admin details dynamically with same  template page.

Answer (score 2):

You can put the details in a conditional:

```
<template name="example">
    {{#if admin}}
        Admin details
    {{/if}}
</template>
```

```
Template.example.admin = function() {
    return Meteor.user() && Meteor.user().admin;
};
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest you use routes for this. This also allows you to control what other users see when they aren't admin and redirect, etc. instead of using a crazy number of conditional statements. For an example of an admin interface that is actually added via a smart package, see the following files, which use **[iron-router](https://github.com/EventedMind/iron-router)**:

> https://github.com/HarvardEconCS/turkserver-meteor/blob/master/admin/clientAdmin.html
>   https://github.com/HarvardEconCS/turkserver-meteor/blob/master/admin/clientAdmin.coffee